# Django / Python - Querying calculated field

Tags: python, django, django-models, sum, aggregate

I have the below models, and want to run a calculation on a foreign key of allocation and then sum the amounts.

```
class Fundraising(models.Model):
    @property
    def amount_raised(self):
        amount_raised = FundraisingDonation.objects.filter(
                            fundraising_event=self,
                            ).aggregate(donationamount=Coalesce(Sum('donationamount'), 0.00))['donationamount']
        return amount_raised

class FundraisingDonation(models.Model):
    donationamount = models.DecimalField(max_digits=11, decimal_places=2, default=0)


class Testmodel(models.Model):
      organisation = models.ForeignKey(Organisation, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
      allocation = models.ForeignKey(Fundraising, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='items')
      percentshare = models.DecimalField(max_digits=11, decimal_places=2, default=0) #SET BY USER

     @property
     def amount(self):
         amount = self.allocation.amount_raised * self.percentshare
         return amount
```

The 'amount' model property above calculates the amount field for each model instance.

I'm trying now to sum up the amounts for each organisation on a new model, however the following doesn't work as I don't believe I can run a query on a calculated field?

```
class Totals(models.Model):
    totals = total + totalB + totalC
    @property
    def total(self):
        total = Testmodel.objects.filter(
                           organisation=self.organisation
                            ).aggregate(amount=Coalesce(Sum('amount'), 0.00))['amount']
```

Is there any way to amend the  last line for this to work, or to reperform the calculation in this line? I also tried aggregate(Sum(amount_raised * percentshare)), but this didn't seem to work either?

Answer (score 0):

You can not aggregate on a `@property`, since that property is unknown at the database side.

What you can do is [**`.annotate(…)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#annotate) the queryset of `Organisation`s for example:

```
from django.db.models import F, Sum

Organisation.objects.annotate(
    total=Sum(
        F('testmodel__allocation__amount_raised') * F('testmodel__percentshare')
    )
)
```

Each `Organisation` that arises from this queryset will have an extra attribute named `.total` that contains the sum of the `amount_raised` values for the *related* `testmodel` items, multiplied with `percentshare`.

**EDIT**: since the `amount_raised` is a property, we need to aggregate on the `FundraisingDonation` model, so:

```
from django.db.models import F, Sum, Value
from django.db.models.functions import Coalesce

Organisation.objects.annotate(
    total=Coalesce(Sum(
        F('testmodel__allocation__fundraising__donationamount') *
        F('testmodel__percentshare'), Value(0))
    )
)
```

Comment: Thanks. although not certain this approach works as amount_raised is also a property field? 
I also need to be able to sum the total attribute with 2 other total attributes for an overall total (i.e Summedtotals = TotalA + TotalB + TotalC - so if this is just an annotation attribute I wouldn't be able to add the result to anything else?

Comment: @Oliver: can you share the relevant parts of your `FundraisingDonation` model?

Comment: updated the question with the relevant parts of each model - I essentially need to run a calculation (summing totals) on a calculation (@property def total) on a calculation (fundraising.allocation.amount_raised)!

Comment: @Oliver: the `FundraisingDonation` has a `ForeignKey` to `Fundraising`?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. FundraisingDonation also has this field:     fundraising_event = models.ForeignKey(Fundraising, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214128/discussion-between-oliver-and-willem-van-onsem).